# how to parse json array in django

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am new in django rest api framework and using get i am fetching the a json array whose api is this https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=machine+learning and i am not able to parse it.Actually i want to store all the names and send them to .html file .I have used this code but didnot worked for me.

```
    req = requests.get('https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&
                                query=machine+learning')
    jsonList = []
    jsonList.append(req.json())
    print(jsonList[0])
    userData = {}
    for value in jsonList[0]:
        parsedData.append(value["name"])
        print(value["name"])
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

Comment: How did it "not work for you"? Please don't just say that it didn't work. Include the expected behavior and what behavior you saw.

Comment: i was getting this error Exception Value:  

string indices must be integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Django.

The way to get to the `name` attribute inside `elements` (there are actually many elements, each one has a 'name`):

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query = machine + learning')

json_data = json.loads(req.text)

for element in json_data['elements']:
    print(element['name'])

>> Speak English Professionally: In Person, Online & On the Phone
   Machine Learning
   Learning How to Learn: Powerful mental tools to help you master tough subjects
   .
   .
```

**Update**:

To display the names in a view:

Considering that you have a very basic template:

```
{% for name in names %}
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Inside your view, considering you already have the above code, and you stored all the names in a list called `names`:

```
return render(request, 'app/profile.html', context={'names': names}, status=200)  
# it's always a good habit to return an HTTP status code
```

Comment: DeepSpace I donot want to print in console.i want to store all name and send to .html file so that i can run a loop and display those names, so how to do this,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a Json Array without A Name/Key as shown below you can do, it is very similar to accepted answer below with slight difference of not having key/name in the Json Array

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "user": 2129
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "user": 2129
    }
]
```

**In View**

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/some-api/', headers=headers)

users = json.loads(response.text)
for user in users:
    print(user)

return render(request, "web_client/mine.html", {"data": users, "page": "mine"})
```

**In Template**

```
{% for row in data %}
  {{ row.some_key_to_print }}
{% endfor %}
```